# Im very unfamiliar with python 2.7. Im not sure how to convert a specific piece of code from 2.7 to 3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have no idea how python 2.7 works. Is there a way for me to convert it to python 3?

```
recipients = ['email@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
sent = 1
print 'Email sent to: %s (%s)' % (", ".join(recipients), sent)
```

Specifically, i'm unsure about the print statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, print is a function. So, you can make this work by changing it to:

```
recipients = ['email@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
sent = 1
print('Email sent to: %s (%s)' % (", ".join(recipients), sent))
```

But you can format using f-strings by changing your print statement like this:

```
print(f'Email sent to: {", ".join(recipients)}')
```

You can read more about f-strings [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

That's the only difference in this piece of code.
You can read more about the changes [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/important-differences-between-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-with-examples/).

Comment: C-style string formatting is deprecated, it's better to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) or [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function

Comment: Hi @DanielKonovalenko: I've added an example using f strings as well. Thanks for reminding.